# vectorized matrix list application in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

the problem i am trying to solve is as follows. I am given a matrix of arbitrary dimension representing indices of a list, and then a list. I would like to get back a matrix with the list elements swapped for the indices. I can't figure out how to do that in a vectorized way:
i.e if `z = [[0,1], [1,0]]` and `list = [20,10]`, i'd want `[[20,10], [10,20]]` returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they both are `np.array`, you can do indexing in a natural way:

```py
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
a = np.array([20, 10])

output = a[z]
print(output)
# [[20 10]
#  [10 20]]
```